# Difference between a Property of an object and a piece of Metadata that describes the object?

Tags: oop, metadata

This is a design question that I am struggling to find an answer too. I am designing a system that is predicated around an object and I need to identify and detail all the data required to run a business that uses these objects. The point I am struggling with is what is a piece of property of this object versus a piece of metadata, what is the difference and why should I care.

I think a propoerty is something that must exist for that object to exist. Whereas a piece of metadata is a piece of data that describes that object for the purpose of a business process.

As an example I'll say this object is a Car and I am in the business of selling Cars. Properties of the Car would be Make, Colour, Engine Size. Whereas a piece of metadata would be IsSold or ForSale, where the metadata relates to the business process of selling cars.

Price seems like it would be a property of the Car but why would it be a property as opposed to a piece of metadata?

I am hoping I am making sense here. Thoughts/advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confusing data versus metadata. All of those properties you listed would be considered data/properties, including IsSold and ForSale. The way to think about the difference between a property and metadata is this:

> If the data describes the object (color describes car), then it's a
>   property.
>
> If the data describes the data/property itself (character length of
>   the color property; orange would be 6), then it's metadata.

ForSale describes the object, so it's a property.

Comment: Not sure I agree. According to wikipedia "Metadata (metacontent) is defined as data providing information about one or more aspects of the data, such as: Purpose of the data". The example given is "A text document's metadata may contain information about how long the document is...".

By this definition ForSale describes the purpose of the data, the car in this example. Storing ForSale as a Property of the Car means all Cars are for sale but that is not true in all instances. ForSale is only relevant to the business of selling cars. I would say ForSale is metadata as opposed to a property.

Comment: You may be over-thinking this. The first thing in the wikipedia article is this: "The term metadata is ambiguous." Not all cars with a ForSale property are for sale; only the ones where ForSale == true. Metadata is typically data about other data (not about the object itself). Your example is a good one to make it confusing, but ForSale is about the car (object) not other data.